# Implementing Bootstrap Menu in Angular JS 1.5

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

Greetings for the day Everyone,

I am trying to implement Bootstrap Parent - Child Menu using AngularJS 1.5 and I am not able to implement the carret & child menu. So can anyone pls help me out on this.

Array Schema are as follows: ID column random Generated number, ParentCategoryID = 0 means its a Parent Menu & if the value is greater than 0 then it means ParentCategoryID is the child of the Parent "ID".

```
ID : 1, LinkText: "Activity", URL: "/CRM/Activity/", ParentCategoryID: 0 
ID : 2, LinkText : "Business Partners", URL : "/CRM/BusinessPartner/", ParentCategoryID : 0
ID : 3, LinkText : "Sales", URL : "#", ParentCategoryID : 0 
ID : 4, LinkText : "Sales Opportunities", URL : "/CRM/OpportunityMaster/", ParentCategoryID : 3 
ID : 5, LinkText: "Sales Quotation", URL: "/CRM/SalesQuotation/", ParentCategoryID: 3 
ID : 6, LinkText : "Sales Order", URL : "/CRM/SalesOrder/", ParentCategoryID : 3
ID : 7, LinkText : "Delivery", URL : "/CRM/Delivery/", ParentCategoryID : 0 
ID : 8, LinkText : "Service Call", URL : "/CRM/ServiceCall/", ParentCategoryID : 0 
ID: 9, LinkText: "Customer Equipment Card", URL: "/CRM/EquipmentCard/", ParentCategoryID: 0
```

[image]

**Actual HTML of Bootstrap 3.5.5 Menu** [View Demo](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_dropdown&stacked=h)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Since the menu from database, I am not able to implement its child menu please suggest me solution on this. [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/nLGbTUUhbn0280f3uGgU/)

Comment: Post your code so that we can know how far you have done and at what point you are facing problem.

Comment: @AKA Please find Plunker link...

Comment: where and what you want to show in child menu items?

Comment: @tanmay please find my updated comments.

Comment: @RahulJain is the menulist going to be hardcoded or it would be dynamic? can't we add the child menu items as an array inside the object of it's parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this modified code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link data-require="angular.js@1.5.0" data-semver="1.5.0" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link data-require="angular.js@1.5.0" data-semver="1.5.0" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.0" data-semver="1.5.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.0" data-semver="1.5.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.2.4/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.0" data-semver="1.5.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="ACE" ng-controller="LayoutController">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header"></div>
                <!--ng-if="(MenuList | filter:{ParentCategoryID : menu.ID}).length >= 0"-->
                <script type="text/ng-template" id="treeMenu">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"  href="{{menu.URL}}">{{menu.LinkText}}
                     <span ng-if="(MenuList | filter:{ParentCategoryID : menu.ID}).length > 0">
                     <span class="caret"></span>
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li ng-repeat="menu in MenuList | filter: {ParentCategoryID : menu.ID}">
                          <a href="#">{{menu.LinkText}}</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </span>
                    </a>
                </script>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown" ng-repeat="menu in MenuList | filter: {ParentCategoryID : 0}" ng-include="'treeMenu'">
                    </li>
                    <li id="btnLogOut"><a href="#">Log out</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: user7761868 thanks for your reply but now the <a> is not working for the parent menu...  This attribute is giving problem => data-toggle="dropdown" but If i remove this atribute then submenu is not working.

Comment: Hi Rahul, thanks for the feedback. As you said this issue is because of data-toggle attribute. The way to achieve the functionality is to add data-toggle attribute conditionally. We can achieve this with ng-attr attribute.

This is the snippet.

`<a class="dropdown-toggle" href="{{menu.URL}}" ng-attr-data-toggle="{{menu.URL == '#'?'dropdown':''}}">{{menu.LinkText}}`

Comment: need your help... can we chat ?

Comment: sure Rahul, we can chat, let me know when is the good time for you.

Comment: Actually I am facing the following issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43424624/page-freezes-in-angular-js-1-5 I am ready to talk... my skype id is rahuljain257